# Why is a dropdown retaining value automatically in MVC5 Razor Engine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a MVC5 ASP.Net view with Razor engine. 
I am finding that a drop-down created by Html.DropdownList automatically retains its value. There is no model binding for the drop-down.

**Question**: **Why is this happening?** I thought we had to pass a third parameter to helper below to specify its selected value, but it seems I don't have to.

```
@Html.DropDownList("SearchCondition", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["SearchConditions"])
```

**UPDATE 1:**

My controller action code is as below, which gets called when the view with above drop-down posts back.

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder,
            String SearchField,
            String SearchCondition,
            String SearchText,
            String Export,
            int? PageSize,
            int? page,
            string command)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();

            if ((command == "Show All"))
            {
                SearchText = string.Empty;
            }
            else if (command == "Export")
            {
                ExportData(Export);
            }

            ViewData["SearchFields"] = GetFields();

            ViewData["SearchConditions"] = GetNumericConditions(SearchCondition);
            ViewData["Exports"] = GetExports();
            ViewData["PageSizes"] = GetPageSizes();

            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.OrderIDSortParm = sortOrder == "OrderID_asc" ? "OrderID_desc" : "OrderID_asc";
            ViewBag.ProductIDSortParm = sortOrder == "ProductID_asc" ? "ProductID_desc" : "ProductID_asc";
            ViewBag.UnitPriceSortParm = sortOrder == "UnitPrice_asc" ? "UnitPrice_desc" : "UnitPrice_asc";
            ViewBag.QuantitySortParm = sortOrder == "Quantity_asc" ? "Quantity_desc" : "Quantity_asc";
            ViewBag.DiscountSortParm = sortOrder == "Discount_asc" ? "Discount_desc" : "Discount_asc";
            ViewBag.SearchField = SearchField;
            ViewBag.SearchCondition = SearchCondition;
            ViewBag.SearchText = SearchText;
            ViewBag.Export = Export;
            ViewBag.PageSize = PageSize;
            ViewBag.FilterText = SearchText;
            //SOME MORE CODE FOLLOWS below that has been omitted

            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(Query.ToPagedList(pageNumber, (PageSize ?? 5)));
      }
```

Comment: The value of the `<select>` is the value of your property `SearchCondition`. If you select a value, when you post back, that value is stored in `ModelState` so if you return the view, the value is retained.

Comment: I have added ModelState.Clear() at start of my action method but its still retaining the posted value of drop-down.

Answer (score 1):

There is a model binding, `SearchCondition`, and then the value and display value are inferred because you're using the `SelectListItem` for the list.

Comment: My dropdown is not bound to any Model, but there is ViewBag.SearchCondition value being set in my controller. Would that be getting used without me specifying it in the Html helper?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the value is being defaulted in the ViewData in the controller action.  Can you post the controller code?